# Configuring an Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, security, web-server, lamp, ubuntu-20.04

this is the first time I am setting up an Ubuntu server. It is going to run a low-usage app for a company but I want to make sure not to leave any security issues out.

1) I installed a fresh Ubuntu desktop 20.04 on a Dell OptiPlex i5 machine. (which was a bit tricky)

2) Added LAMP and SSH-Server using `tasksel`

3) Configured mysql with a new user and a strong password. Disabled root user and non-local access.

4) Enabled firewall and allowed `ssh, http, https` ports

Do you think is this configuration fair enough to run server securely? What other precautions do you recommend?

Note: I did not installed an Ubuntu Server edition because I want to have a GUI also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimally you'll want to open as little as possible to the outside world. If, for example, you don't need to allow access to ssh from the Internet, don't. If your use case requires an open-to-the-world ssh server, make sure you configure it to require asymmetric key authentication rather than username/password credentials.

I would advise against running a full desktop installation on a server, both because of added overhead and because of the larger potential attack surface. Become comfortable configuring your services through the CLI - it will benefit you anyway; at the very least when you have no way of rectifying an issue other than via ssh.

When configuring TLS for your web service, check it with something like [ssllabs](https://ssllabs.com), and also [check your security headers](https://securityheaders.com) to make life slightly harder for a potential attacker.

Additional security is largely up to the app you're running, of course, as long as you make sure your environment stays up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install antivirus software such as ClamAV, enable SELinux if it's going to be available to the public, and make sure that `ssh` is not available to the public as it's a common attack vector. For web applications, be sure that the files and directories are not owned by the Apache user (if that's what you're using) or the users of any of the services. Instead, create a group with write access to run the apps so that even if it's compromised, it can't change permissions. For MySQL, make sure that you have methods in place to protect against SQL injection and other attacks. Auditing and logging are also important and you also need to work with networking and infosec at the company to make sure that there other protections in place.

The last thing that you can do is get rid of the GUI as it creates more vectors that need to be secured. There is no reason to have a GUI on a server as in addition to what I just stated, it requires more resources that could be allocated elsewhere. You don't need to have Ubuntu Server but make sure that you are using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which is supported until 2030.